# Using conditional formatting to identify formulas (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a long sheet where some cells have typed values and some other cells have formulas. And i need to have a visual identification of the kind (number or formula) of each cell.

Is it possible to do by using conditional formatting? If yes, how?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Might this be an option? => Libreoffice menu:View > Show formula (CTRL+\`). The same is available in Excel, but I do not remember where (the shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+D if I remember correctly)

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't solve completely my problem but helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is relatively simple using the [`ISFORMULA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isformula-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5) function, available since Excel 2013.

- Select your range
- New conditional formatting formula, e.g:

  ```
  =ISFORMULA(A1)
  ```
- Apply your formatting
- Confirm

[image]

---

Prior to Excel 2013, you may want to use a custom [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818065/9758194).

- Paste this code in a module:

  ```
  Function ISFORMULA(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
      ISFORMULA = target.HasFormula
  End Function
  ```
- Repeat the exact same steps as the above example

Comment: Thank you, but my Excel is 2010...

Comment: @Marcelo, edited

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!